# How to add a Chatbot build in React to an HTML website using iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

I've developed a Chatbot in React. Now I want to add into into website using iFrame. The problem is I want the chat window to open when the user clicks on the chatbutton inside iframe.
How can we make the iFrame height and width adjustable to make sure entire chat window is visible.